# Convergence of a power series at points where ratio test is inconclusive

Tags: power-series

I need to find the interval of convergence of the following power series using either the ratio test , integral test or comparison test. Using the ratio test I found that it will converge for $ -4 < x < 4 $ but it proves inconclusive  at $ x = \pm 4 $
$$ 
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2 x^n}{(2n)!}
$$

Comment: Do you mean $(2n)!$ on the denominator?

Comment: oh yes . Im sorry. Ive edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x=\pm 4$, 
$$
|\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} x^n|=\frac{n! 2^n }{1\cdot 3\cdot \cdots (2n-1)}=\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot \cdots (2n)}{1\cdot 3\cdot \cdots (2n-1)}
$$
This does not converge to zero, so the series is divergent at both points.

Comment: Please could you show me how you arrived at the 2nd step from the 1st? I get that you first cancelled $n!$ from the numerator and denominator but that leaves $(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+n)$ in the denominator. Then how does it give $1\cdot3...(2n-1)$ when further divided by $2^n$ ?

Comment: Split the $(2n)!$ two parts: product of even numbers which is $2^n n!$, and product of odd numbers $1\cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1)$.